# React-Native: Cannot update babel to ES7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to use the new ES7 features async/await but as far as I can see in my react-native node_modules, I don't have them there.

I had the react-native version 0.31 and I just updated it to 0.32, I can see that babel still is not updating with the ES7 features so I cannot use the async/await. Do you know a way how I can manage to make it work?

Comment: Did you tried running your application with async code? React native use babel-preset-react-native which contains async plugin as well. I am using async in my apps as well.

Comment: Yes and than im getting a console.error with the message Unexpected token.

Comment: async/await is not a feature of ES7. It's going to be released next year as part of ES2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install a couple of babel plugins, then you can use ES7 decorators and save it in devDependencies:

**1- babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy**

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy --save-dev
```

**2- babel-preset-react-native-stage-0**

```
npm i babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Finally Create **.babelrc** in root project folder file if not exist and add these lines:

```
{
 'presets': ['react-native'],
 'plugins': ['transform-decorators-legacy']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Babel doesn't ship with async/await by default. To make use of them install this plugin:

```
npm install babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions
```

and use it like this in your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["syntax-async-functions"]
}
```

Reference: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-async-functions/

Comment: Now it does come with babel in the react-native module.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question then? The issue is that you don't have babel installed?

Comment: My mistake, hope is better now.

Comment: I have like 20 .babelrc files, im not sure which one is the good one ...

Comment: how do you have 20? There should just be one in the root of your project. If it's not there you can just create it

Comment: I can see that every node_module from react-native which comes with babel has one.

Comment: Yeah don't add it to one in a node_module. Create one in your root directory